# Mahout 0.9 on Hadoop 0.20.2

Tags: hadoop, mahout

Can Mahout 0.9 work on Hadoop 0.20.2?

I have downloaded Mahout 0.9 and I see that it is based on Hadoop 1.2.1. On the other hand, I have an already deployed cluster with Hadoop 0.20.2.

How can I make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `Apache Mahout 0.9` is compatible with `Apache Hadoop 1.2.1`
You can have a look at: [https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/pom.xml#L107) and according to that POM file, it looks like Hadoop 0.20.2 isn't supported.

Comment: Ok, but only with it? There is no way to use it with cluster on which Hadoop 0.20.2 is installed?

Comment: Thank you. I'll wait a bit more before accepting your answer, hopping to some solution that could help me considering my constraint.